# Hangfire - log processing history

Tags: hangfire

I cant find a way to log to the processing history =(. Im sure its possible! Im missing something here right?

I want to do something like this:[image]

Does someone know how to do this?

Comment: tell us you line of thinking

Comment: I need a way to see more than just that the job succeeded in the dashboard. It would be sufficient to se that 300 records where updated or something like that..

Comment: As a hack, you can return a string that contains a message. It will be displayed in the Succeeded state box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this:

```
JobHistoryRenderer.Register(SucceededState.StateName, MySucceededRenderer);
```

Check SucceededRenderer in Github if you want to know about the implementation.

Comment: and how to use it?